# Chrome uses proxy even though proxy option is deselected

Tags: google-chrome, proxy

My Chrome browser is in a weird state. It claims that it's configured to use a proxy server and that it can't connect to that server. Problem is, when I go to the LAN settings, the option to use a proxy server is deselected. Toggling this setting has no effect.

I've tried reinstalling Chrome but the problem persists.

Any idea on how I can get it to stop trying to use whatever proxy it thinks it's configured for?

Answer (score 0):

try selecting no proxy in network settings of chrome. i'm not sure whether this going to work but it is worth trying. its not going to do any harm.
hope you find a solution

Comment: That's what I did (when I mentioned the LAN settings above). It shows as deselected.